# Assets are not compiling/loaded in development

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, asset-pipeline, assets

I took over a existing project and i would like do some updates but i don't know how correctly launch it in development environment,

Its Rails 5 app and i can't contact the past developer

The page loading is high and its like the majority of the front end is not load

I tried many things before with webpack and rails compilation but nothing work
I would like know how to fix it and what is "the best way to do" when we start coding on legacy code

[image: in local]

[image: in Production]

EDIT

All CSS/SCSS and JS are in webpacker folders, i never use webpacker before for my Rails projects so maybe it can from a simple missing plugin or something like that

Comment: It doesn't sound like an assets issue to me, but rather a CSS / SCSS one. Can you please check, in your browser, if there is any 404 error about files not being found? Also, can you share all the possible configurations concerning the problem?

Comment: No i didn't have errors about missing files in browser or server logs@briosheje